# How can i download csv file and store it on public folder in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I have a link of csv. So what i want is when my page load for the first time i want to download the csv file from a link and store it on public folder.So that i can take it from there and map its data by converting it into JSON.

Comment: here is the link: "https://connect.emgsrv.com/wT3Kjzu4B3P43VQikYjq/wT3Kjzu4B3P43VQikYjq.CSV"

Comment: you cannot do it using react alone, you will have to create an additional script and fire it during `npm start` to download the file that you require and convert it to json

Comment: Thanks for this 
Can i directly read the csv of that url in my react?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need an express server. After that, create a file csv.js (maybe inside the "utils" folder) in your backend.
Inside write this code:

```
const {
    readJSON,
    writeJSON,
    writeFile,
    readFile,
    remove,
    createReadStream,
    createWriteStream,
  } = fs;

import fs from "fs-extra";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { dirname, join } from "path";

const authorsJSONPath = join(
    dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
    "../authors.json"
  );


export const getAuthorsReadableStream = () => createReadStream(authorsJSONPath);
```

Then of course you need the server, and the routes. Import the router in your server and specify an endpoint.
If you know how to do that, create this route and import what you need. You will need the package json2csv

import json2csv from "json2csv";

```
// Get CSV files
router.get("/download/csv", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename=Authors.csv`);
    const source = getAuthorsReadableStream();
    const transform = new json2csv.Transform({
      fields: ["id", "name", "surname", "email", "dateOfBirth", "avatar"],
    });
    const destination = res;
    pipeline(source, transform, destination, (err) => {
      if (err) next(err);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

If you want to just have that data to map through it, and not to be downloaded by the user, create a JSON file and map through it instead.

For any further support or issue just ask here.

Comment: But i am not getting data from that url
i have mapped the data into json from a downloaded file by selecting it from local as input
what i want is to directly fetch data from url
i need help in this

Comment: If you want to fetch the data and work with it, and not to be downloaded by the user from an endpoint. Consider deploying your json data to Heroku maybe and then fetch the data as you usually do in React with fetch or axios

Comment: my point is to fetch data from this url https://connect.emgsrv.com/D7huMcppWWRaAKMdafZW/D7huMcppWWRaAKMdafZW.CSV
is there any possible ways to directly fetch data from this url as it is not a normal backend api

Comment: axios and fetch is not giving any response in this url so im stuck